# blpAuthenticate issue with Rblpapi in R

Tags: r, bloomberg, blpapi

I am unable to authenticate my Bloomberg data connection using the Rblpapi function, blpAuthenticate. I have used the following:
uuid = Taken from the "IAM " screen, both as a character type as well as numeric
host = Using "CONN ", I have chosen the host name listed "Adapter Info" tab
ip.address = Again, from "CONN ", I have used the IP Address shown there (as a character)

If I use the blpConnect function, as specified in help, I can connect but if I call the defaultConnection() function, I get an error stating this function cannot be found. If I alternatively call the blpConnect function in this call, the process just hangs and never completes.

Any suggestions please on whether I have either set the parameters, or if there are other checks I need to make in order to connect?

Answer (score 0):

The only time you need to use blpAuthenticate() should be when using Server API. If you are a standard Bloomberg user then you should just be able to run blpConnect() and create a session. After that point you can use Rblpapi functions to request data. Take a look at the [Rblpapi vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rblpapi/vignettes/rblpapi-intro.html) for more information.